# TFF: accuracy is not increasing while simulating random samples of users

Tags: tensorflow-federated

By simulating a tff code with random choice of clients in each round, I find that the accuracy increases to 0.9 then relapses to 0.5 and then from 0.8 to 0.6 and so on, it is not increasing.
have you any idea? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By chance is this a comparison of *training* accuracy and *evaluation* accuracy?  In federated learning these two have different interpretations than the standard centralized machine learning setting.

In federated learning, *training* accuracy is often hard to interpret because it is the accuracy over *client local* model on the *client local* dataset. The *client local* dataset is a subset of the global distribution, with potentially a very different distribution.

Especially if there is high amounts of client drift (taking many *client local* training steps on a *client local* dataset that has large distribution differences), after averaging the individual client updates, the progress of the *global* model maybe far less than what the individual clients each round. Hence the *evaluation* accuracy at the end of the round maybe quite a bit worse than the *training* accuracy. In a "healthy" training process, this is expected to catch up after enough rounds have occurred.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. So please, if I use evaluation accuracy, How we can explain fluctuation of evaluation accuracy values?