# Accuracy of non IID is better than accuracy of IID data

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I work with TFF 0.12.0, with the same architecture of ResNet50, I execute an example of IID dataset, and an example with non-IID dataset, but I find that accuracy of non-IID dataset is better (high) than accuracy of IID dataset especially in the first rounds.

Comment: There are many notions of IID (labels, features, amount of examples, etc), it may help answers to clarify what kinds of IID. Also note that metrics in Federated Learning can be hard to interpret (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61700643/14692)), clarifying whether this is training or evaluation accuracy is important.

Comment: evaluation accuracy